# Display image over another image, with cutting edges on resize (responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to display one image over another. It have to be responsive, with cutting image's edges if i resize. (see the pictures. i can't directly embedded images yet, without 10 reputation). How can i do that?
Here's the code:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="content-item_1">
    <img class="img1" src="photo/image1.png" />
    text1. text text
   </div>
<div class="content-item_2">
    <img class="img2" src="photo/image1.png" />
    text2. text text
   </div>
</div>
```

Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/5woswyxc/2/

but image 2 have to be slighty over image 1, if it resize. 
and when size is reduced - text 1 must move on the top on image 2. 
(image1 is moved to bottom)

[resized layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTLm2.png)

Comment: Show us your CSS, what have you done so far?

Comment: We need to see whatever CSS you have so far, but it is likely your problem can be fixed by specifying the width of your elements in percentages.

Comment: Alos, maybe link us to a working example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: now i have this code https://jsfiddle.net/xw1eysvj/

Comment: i update question: but image 2 have to be slighty over image 1, if it resize. and when size is reduced - text 1 must move on the top on image 2. (image1 is moved to bottom)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
  <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="parent">
                <img class="image1" src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" />
                <img class="image2" src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .parent {
                position: relative;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: blue;
                width: 450px;
                height: 320px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .image1 {
                position: relative;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            .image2 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 30px;
                left: 70px;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
```